# Browser differences with insertUnorderedList

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

So I'm trying to use content editable divs along with `document.execCommand` to give something approximating a WYSIWYG editor. It works great in Chrome. In IE, however, the `insertUnorderedList` and `insertOrderedList` commands are behaving poorly. Specifically, if it's on a blank line it just unfocuses, rather than inserting a bulleted (or numbered) list, as it would in Chrome. If you have a section highlighted, it selects EVERYTHING and then sets up the bulleted (or numbered) list, rather than just setting up the selection to be in a list.

HTML:

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">Test<br/>Test</div>
<div class="buttons">
<button onclick="insertUnordered();">Unordered List</button>
<button onclick="insertOrdered();">Ordered List</button>
</div>
```

Code:

```
function insertUnordered() {
    document.execCommand("insertUnorderedList");
}

function insertOrdered() {
    document.execCommand("insertOrderedList");
}
```

I also have this jsfiddle set up: http://jsfiddle.net/sbazp/1/ If you look in IE vs. Chrome, you can see what I'm talking about. (You need to click in the editable area first before the buttons do anything).

Is there any easy way to work around this, or should I just go for some WYSIWYG plugin?

Comment: Many of the `document.execCommand` functions only have limited support in IE. This link has more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript">

function insertUnordered() {
    document.execCommand("insertUnorderedList");
}

function insertOrdered() {
    document.execCommand("insertOrderedList");
}


</script>


</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable="true"><ol><li>Foo</li><li>sadasda</li><li>asd</li><li>asd</li><li>asd</li></ol></div>
<div class="buttons">
<button onclick="insertUnordered();">Unordered List</button>
<button onclick="insertOrdered();">Ordered List</button>
</div>

</body></html>
```